# Warning: Undefined variable $post in C:\xampp\htdocs\… after PHP upgrade

Tags: custom-taxonomy, woocommerce-offtopic

I use localhost for testing and debugging sites, before making changes to the live site. Because MySQL failed in XAMPP, I had to install XAMPP from scratch.

I'm now using PHP version 8.0.3.  Everything worked yesterday, so it must have something to do with upgrading my version of PHP.

This code used to work.  It displayed the artist name (custom product taxonomy) with the associated product in WooCommerce.  Now, it's absolutely not working.

> Warning: Undefined variable $post in C:\xampp\htdocs\…

This was my code:

```
<div style="background-color: #f6f6f6 !important;">
<?php $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_artist' );
    if ( !empty( $terms ) ){
        // get the first term
        $term = array_shift( $terms );
    }
    $artist = $term->slug;
    $url = get_site_url();
    $name = ucwords(str_replace('-', ' ', $artist));
?>
    <div class="by-artist" style="color: #BCA47B !important; background-color: #F6F6F6; font-size: 14px; padding: 5px 0px 10px 0px">
    <a href="<?php echo $url . '/artists/' . $artist; ?>">
    <?php echo $name; ?></a>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Does anyone know why this would stop working in PHP 8xx?  More importantly, how do I fix it.

Thank you.

Comment: Where are you getting the $post variable? Is it a custom query or have you declared the global?

Comment: Abhik, this is my line of code.  I'm not sure I understand.  The post ID is just the post id, of the item in the online store.

$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_artist' );